# Как сравнить два движения мышкой / сравнение двух списков координат с разным числом элементов и учетом направления

Tags: python, android, курсор

Пишу приложение в котором управление происходит жестами мышки. Изначально в программе я сам рисую мышкой и сохраняю её движения в виде списка по координат, далее к этому списку привязывается функция. Если пользователь в программе провёл мышкой по тому же пути, то должна выполнится функция.

У меня на этом этапе есть два списка с движением мышки. Как их сравнить? Требования к алгоритму:

1. Сравнивать списки с разным числом элементов.
2. Учитывать направление движения.
3. Сравнивать должен примерно, желательно с коэффициентом сходства, где 1 - одинаковые списки, а 0 - совсем разные. Пробовал делать маску с использованием numpy, но ни направление, ни рисунок не учитывался

Comment: Если старт одинаковый, то можете попробовать растеризовать 1-е движение в небольшйю картинку с толщиной линии, например, 30пикс, а потом проверить, попадают ли кординаты второго движения в эту область.

Comment: Почитай про динамическое программирование и алгоритм Левенштейна. Мне кажется ты можешь вдохновится его алгосом и решить свою проблему.